# How can I pipe the stdout of an exec function into the reader of another?

Tags: mongodb, go, amazon-s3

I'm trying to stream the stdout from mongodump into s3. I have gotten the syntax for the S3 arbitrary-length stream right, but I don't understand how to couple the two functions. I don't want to process the entire mongodump command before I start uploading to S3. This is what I have so far:

```
dumpCmd := exec.Command("mongodump", "--host", "<host>", "--port", "<port>", "--archive")
dumpCmd.Stdout = os.Stdout


uploader := s3manager.NewUploader(session.New(&aws.Config{Region: aws.String("us-east-1")}))
result, err := uploader.Upload(&s3manager.UploadInput{
    Body:   dumpCmd.Stdout,
    Bucket: aws.String("myBucket"),
    Key:    aws.String("myKey"),
})
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalln("Failed to upload", err)
}

log.Println("Successfully uploaded to", result.Location)
```

unfortunately dumpCmd.Stdout is a writer, not a reader, and I don't know how to pipe the output of the writer into the reader.

After using a pipe I'm now getting a new error, which may belong in a new question:

```
dumpCmd := exec.Command("mongodump", "--host", "<host>", "--port", "<port>", "--archive")
body, err := dumpCmd.StdoutPipe()
if err != nil {
    // handle error
}

if err := dumpCmd.Start(); err != nil {
    // handle error
}

uploader := s3manager.NewUploader(session.New(&aws.Config{Region: aws.String("us-east-1")}))
result, err := uploader.Upload(&s3manager.UploadInput{
    Body:   body,
    Bucket: aws.String("myBucket"),
    Key:    aws.String("myKey"),
})
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalln("Failed to upload", err)
}

if err := dumpCmd.Wait(); err != nil {
    // handle error
}

log.Println("Successfully uploaded to", result.Location)
```

error:

```
2016/03/10 12:39:18 Failed to upload MultipartUpload: upload multipart failed
    upload id: QOWW4jBHH4PKjs1Tloc8dlCTtFN94vDHIJIWJChsrjxLZggScZbRUhM4FU9V.xOnIg9uYnBWqOA1x1xqStfA1p8vdAOHNyUp4gOO5b1gbuXvUitQyLdfFhKg9MnyxsV1
caused by: RequestError: send request failed
caused by: Put https://myBucket/myKey?partNumber=1&uploadId=QOWW4jBHH4PKjs1Tloc8dlCTtFN94vDHIJIWJChsrjxLZggScZbRUhM4FU9V.xOnIg9uYnBWqOA1x1xqStfA1p8vdAOHNyUp4gOO5b1gbuXvUitQyLdfFhKg9MnyxsV1: read |0: illegal seek
exit status 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [pipe](https://godoc.org/os/exec#Cmd.StdoutPipe) to connect the output of the command to the input of the upload.

The tricky issue here is that the uploader [seeks on the body](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/blob/996f601d8198d4fdc49bb5d93c73f27a6bdfe900/service/s3/s3manager/upload.go#L383), but the seek is not supported by the pipe. To circumvent this, a wrapper is created around the pipe to hide the Seek method from the uploader.

```
dumpCmd := exec.Command("mongodump", "--host", "<host>", "--port", "<port>", "--archive")
body, err := dumpCmd.StdoutPipe()
if err != nil {
    // handle error
}

if err := dumpCmd.Start(); err != nil {
    // handle error
}

// Wrap the pipe to hide the seek methods from the uploader
bodyWrap := struct {
    io.Reader
}{body}

uploader := s3manager.NewUploader(session.New(&aws.Config{Region: aws.String("us-east-1")}))
result, err := uploader.Upload(&s3manager.UploadInput{
    Body:   bodyWrap,
    Bucket: aws.String("net-openwhere-mongodb-snapshots-dev"),
    Key:    aws.String("myKey"),
})
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalln("Failed to upload", err)
}

if err := dumpCmd.Wait(); err != nil {
   // handle error
}

log.Println("Successfully uploaded to", result.Location)
```

Comment: Thanks, that got me closer to working code I think. new info above

Comment: Unfortunately the uploader is exiting before receiving any data. I'm getting a 0 byte file while expecting around 600 Meg

Comment: @smiller171 What is the error reported by the uploader?

Comment: no error: '2016/03/10 12:56:42 Successfully uploaded to https://myBucket.s3.amazonaws.com/myKey'

Comment: I think it was my bad, one second

Comment: I had foolishly copied in the obfuscated variables instead of using the correct values.

Comment: Hm, I do not understand - your `bodyWrap` is a struct with one field? But `Body` of `UploadInput` must be the `io.Reader`, not a struct.

Comment: @VitalyZdanevich Methods on [embedded fields](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types) are promoted to the containing struct. The value `bodyWrap`satisfies the `io.Reader` interface because the `Read` method from the anonymous `io.Reader` field is promoted to the struct.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `io.Copy` method ([godoc](https://godoc.org/io#Copy)), which is defined as follow:

> func Copy
>
> func Copy(dst Writer, src Reader) (written int64, err error)
>
> Copy copies from src to dst until either EOF is reached on src or an
>   error occurs. It returns the number of bytes copied and the first
>   error encountered while copying, if any.
>
> A successful Copy returns err == nil, not err == EOF. Because Copy is
>   defined to read from src until EOF, it does not treat an EOF from Read
>   as an error to be reported.
>
> If src implements the WriterTo interface, the copy is implemented by
>   calling src.WriteTo(dst). Otherwise, if dst implements the ReaderFrom
>   interface, the copy is implemented by calling dst.ReadFrom(src).

Comment: I've looked at this a few times, but I'm a complete newb and have no idea how to implement it

Comment: Actually I don't think this solves my problem at all. The uploader function can already copy off of a reader, but I don't have a reader, I have a writer (dumpCmd.Stdout)